# Recebendo e-mail sem dados

Tags: post, phpmailer

Criei um formulário usando o phpmailer, mas todo dia chega um email em branco, sem ter preenchido o nome, telefone ou email. Creio que seja um robô de busca, alguém sabe como posso remover ele? pois fica atrapalhando minhas métricas.

Resumindo. 
todo dia as 19:46pm, chega esse email em branco pra mim.
http://www.google.com/url?url=www.salusplanosdesaude.com.br&yahoo.com

Penso em usar o robots.txt, mas será que vai funcionar? alguém pode me ajudar por favor. ;)

esse é o meu form ;)

```
                                    <form method= "POST" class="mb-0" action="includes-site/enviar.php" id="formcadastro" >
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Primeiro Nome</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control"id="nome">
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Telefone</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" onkeypress="mascara(this)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--block mt-10" value="enviar">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="titulo" value="<?php echo $tit;?>">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

esse é o enviar

```
    <?php
// Adiciona o arquivo class.phpmailer.php - você deve especificar corretamente o caminho da pasta com o este arquivo.
require_once("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// DEFINIÇÃO DOS DADOS DE AUTENTICAÇÃO - Você deve auterar conforme o seu domínio!
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = ""; // Seu endereço de host SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Define que será utilizada a autenticação -  Mantenha o valor "true"
$mail->Port = ; // Porta de comunicação SMTP - Mantenha o valor "587"
$mail->SMTPSecure = false; // Define se é utilizado SSL/TLS - Mantenha o valor "false"
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // Define se, por padrão, será utilizado TLS - Mantenha o valor "false"
$mail->Username = ''; // Conta de email existente e ativa em seu domínio
$mail->Password = ''; // Senha da sua conta de email

// DADOS DO REMETENTE
$mail->Sender = ""; // Conta de email existente e ativa em seu domínio
$mail->From = ""; // Sua conta de email que será remetente da mensagem
$mail->FromName = "Salus"; // Nome da conta de email

// DADOS DO DESTINATÁRIO
$mail->AddAddress('', 'Leads'); // Define qual conta de email receberá a mensagem
//$mail->AddAddress('recebe2@dominio.com.br'); // Define qual conta de email receberá a mensagem
//$mail->AddCC('copia@dominio.net'); // Define qual conta de email receberá uma cópia
//$mail->AddBCC('copiaoculta@dominio.info'); // Define qual conta de email receberá uma cópia oculta

// Definição de HTML/codificação
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// DEFINIÇÃO DA MENSAGEM
$mail->Subject  = $_POST['titulo']." - ".$_POST['nome']; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " Nome: ".$_POST['nome']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " Telefone: ".$_POST['phone']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= "<br/><br/>Enviado em ". date("d/m/Y")." &agrave;s ".date("H:i:s")." por <a href='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'>".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."</a>";


// ENVIO DO EMAIL
$enviado = $mail->Send();
// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();



// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado do envio (sucesso/erro)
if ($enviado) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso. Favor aguarde nosso contato');</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Ocorreu um erro ao enviar o email. Favor entre em contato conosco pelo email:  ou pelo telefone: ');</script>";
  //echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
  //echo "<b>Detalhes do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'https://salusplanosdesaude.com.br/';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Você fez alguma verificação em seu formulário para não enviar e-mail caso os campos estejam em branco? Talvez pode inserir o Google Recaptcha. Poste aqui seu código para analisarmos :)

Comment: coloquei o código a parte do form e o enviar.php e também coloquei  a validação usando o jquery

Comment: Queira [edit] o post com um [mcve] do problema. Mais detalhes em [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De uma forma rápida e simples, você pode colocar no campo email o atributo `required` e também pode alterar o [type para email](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_email.asp) `type="email"`, no link tem a lista de navegadores que suportam essa alteração.

Você pode colocar o required em outros campos que julgue obrigatórios.

Uma outra solução, que foi apontada pelo Maurício Krüger é o uso de [recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3).

Comment: Entendido, vou tentar, Obrigado! =D

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de você evitar isso, a primeira é a que já foi citada, que seria gerar o Recaptcha. Aqui tem um exemplo passo a passo:

http://acmeextension.com/integrate-google-recaptcha-with-php/

Resumindo o link acima, depois de gerar uma chave para o seu site no Google você adicionaria o seguinte no seu formulário:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer >
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sua_chave_api">
```

E depois alteraria a captura de dados do formulário desta forma:

```html
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
  {
        $secret = 'your_actual_secret_key';
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success)
        {
            //Chave valida, processar o formuláio
        }
        else
        {
           //Houve um erro ao validar o captcha
        }
   }
?>
```

Caso você não queira adicionar o captcha, uma outra alternativa seria gerar uma chave para o formulário, que seria um campo hidden com um valor gerado automaticamente ao abrir a página. Aqui tem um  exemplo disso:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753

Uma outra alternativa, que seria uma variação deste método, seria gerar um prefixo dinâmico para cada campo do formulário. Ao contrário do captcha, seria gerado um campo oculto com um número aleatório criado ao abrir a página

```
"<input type='hidden' name='form_key' id='form_key' value='numero_aleatorio' />
```

Na hora de postar o formulário, seria feita a validação deste número antes de processar os dados do formulário

```html
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post')
{
    if(!isset($_POST['form_key']) || !$formKey->validate())
    {
        //O código postado é diferente do código gerado
    }
    else
    {
        //O código e igual, processar o formulário
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

De forma adicional às soluções listadas pelo Maurício Krüger e pelo Roberto Lima, uma opção é efetuar a validação dos dados também no seu script PHP.

Assim, antes de efetuar o envio do e-mail, você pode testar se os campos possuem conteúdo:

```
if ((!empty($_POST['titulo'])) && (!empty($_POST['nome'])) && 
    (!empty($_POST['email'])) && (!empty($_POST['phone'])))
{
    $enviado = $mail->Send();
    // ...restante do código
}
```